# Gatsby graphql resolver query not returning all fields

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have this resolver query where I filter through all markdown entries to build a collection:

```
export const createResolvers = ({createResolvers}) => {
    const resolvers = {
        Query : {
            allPosts     : {
                type   : ["Post"],
                args   : { limit: `Int`, skip: `Int` },
                resolve: async (source, args, context, info) => {
                    const { entries } = await context.nodeModel.findAll({
                        type : "MarkdownRemark",
                        query: {
                            limit : args.limit,
                            skip  : args.skip,
                            filter: {
                                fileAbsolutePath: {
                                    regex: "//collections/posts//"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    return entries;
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

It returns a collection of type `Post`:

```
    type Post implements Node @dontInfer {
        id: ID!
        html: String
        rawMarkdownBody: String
        fileAbsolutePath: String
        ...
    }
```

The `MarkdownRemark` entries that I select have a `html` field which contains the html output of the markdown file. I can see it in the Graphiql playground/console.

When I query with `allPosts`, the `html` field is empty. I get `rawMarkdownBody` and other fields but not `html`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `createResolvers` runs *after* transformers, so other nodes of type `MarkdownRemark` have already had the `html` field added to them by the time your resolver runs.

You can instead make the change in `createSchemaCustomization`. For example, something like this (probably won't work verbatim, but wanted to get you the gist):

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = async ({
  actions: { createTypes },
  schema,
}) => {
  createTypes([
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "Query"
      fields: {
        allPosts: {
          type: ["Post"],
          args: { limit: `Int`, skip: `Int` },
          resolve: async (source, args, context, info) => {
            // …       
          },
        },
      },
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: I had time to investigate this a little longer meanwhile and it seems that the html field is not rendered until it is first queried and that's why it returns null when I create my resolver. The problem in my case is that I build `allPosts` and then query on it and not on `allMarkdownRemark` which prevents html from being generated at all by `markdownremark` since no query is ran against it. Some insight: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17045

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I'm not sure it matters in your case. If you don't need to query the html field you don't have to worry about it being created dynamically on query by a resolver, you just have to register the schema change before the remark plugin is running.

Comment: it does not seem to work or I'm doing it wrong. I created a demo (branched from a toy blog) and you can have a look at the node.js file. Tried creating it both with `buildObjectType` or further down the pipe with `createResolvers`. No matter where, the html field returns null. Thanks for taking the time so far

Comment: Forgot to add the repo file: https://github.com/ciokan/surron-parts/blob/resolvers/gatsby-node.js#L120 (this is on `resolvers` branch)